# creating photo album in Orchard CMS

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, photo

I tried to create photo album in Orchard CMS, like that in facebook. but didn't find any module to do so, i mean photo album, not photo gallery, photo album that contains folders and subfolders,
thanks.

Comment: The built-in Media Library is organized in folders and subfolders already. I suppose you'd have to build a module to present that on the front-end.

Comment: thanks Bertrand, Is there any ready made module to do so ??

Comment: I don't believe there is